# Creating a POST request with REST template in Spring

Tags: java, spring, post

I am trying to perform a POST request using Java Spring with the REST template from Spring. I am using `urlencoded` content type.

I have tried creating the request by building a `LinkedMultiValueMap` then wrapping it in an `HTTPEntity` then using `postForEntity`

```
String url = "https://url.com/oauth2/token";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        MultiValueMap<String,String> map  = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("client_id", "1234567" );
        map.add("client_secret", "+123456=");
        map.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        map.add("resource", "123456");

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, String.class);
```

I am getting a

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://someurl/oauth2/token": login.url.cn; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: login.somurl.cn
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:744) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:445) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at monitor.ScheduledTasks.getToken(ScheduledTasks.java:63) ~[classes!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: login.url.cn
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Is there an issue with the code or something else? The URL is working, I've tried it on Postman with the same headers and it works perfectly

Comment: Detailed stacktrace for `java.net.UnknownHost exception` please

Comment: Error says the API is down https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html

Comment: API is not down since it is working fine in Postman, plus it is currently in production

Comment: Is this code running on the same system as your Postman? Could be a local DNS configuration issue.

Comment: Im thinking that it might be a proxy issue, however i am using Postman on the same system with no issues with a proxy